# how to apply background iframe to an image?

Tags: css, image, wordpress, background, themes

I am using wordpress blog on my site: http://sunite.co.uk
I want to rotate background image on the current theme:Techified
The background image i want to rotate using openx is: `http://sunite.co.uk/images/background.html`

The code on the stylesheet.css for this is:

```
/************************************CONTENTAREA********************************************/
#content_area {
 border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 background: url(http://sunite.co.uk/images/background.html);
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 position: relative;
```

Please HELP!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify only images and colours as the page background. To have a HTML page as the background of another page (which is a **bad and resource-consuming idea in 99.99999999% of cases!!**) you would have to integrate an absolutely positioned IFRAME to that page.

Comment: It's a bad idea in any case to have an external file (ie hosted on another domain) as background. You never know when it might change.

Comment: so for me to do this i have to go to the header and insert the iframe background from there??

Comment: I don't understand why you want to rotate an image using an *ad server*, but anyway, openX should give you an image URL in that HTML page. You should be able to grab that URL, and use it as backgorund image.

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to a web page - the image on the page is at http://vistawallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2007/03/vista-wallpaper-grass-ripples.jpg

So to set it as a background, use:

```
background: url(http://vistawallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2007/03/vista-wallpaper-grass-ripples.jpg);
```

As Jimmy Shelter says, hot-linking an image off someone else's site is bad practice - what if tomorrow they change the image to something completely inappropriate?